# Dynamically added images not showing

Tags: android, image, dynamic

In this code I'm building a method that adds the same image a number of times to a Relative Layout at runtime. However, the images are not showing up when debugging. The textview that was added is acting normally. Can someone explain how to make the images visible? Thanks in advance.

My Code:

```
public class TestActivity extends Activity {
ArrayClass arraysObject1 = new ArrayClass();
ArrayList<ImageView> mImages = new ArrayList<ImageView>();

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        RelativeLayout layout = new RelativeLayout(this);

        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
        params.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_LEFT, RelativeLayout.TRUE);
        layout.setLayoutParams(params);
        layout.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#FFFFFF"));

        //textview is working
        TextView testText = new TextView(this);
        testText.setText("Alle aangeboden vacatures vindt u hieronder terug.");
        testText.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
    layout.addView(testText);


        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams imgParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        imgParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_IN_PARENT);

        for(int i=0; i<arraysObject1.array1.size(); i++)
        {
            mImages.add(new ImageView(this));
            mImages.get(i).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            mImages.get(i).setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.work);
            mImages.get(i).setLayoutParams(imgParams);

            layout.addView(mImages.get(i));

        }
        setContentView(layout);
    }
}
```

Comment: Too many ``ImageViews`` might throw ``OutOfMemoryException``. I guess :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your cycle `for(int i=0; i < arraysObject1.array1.size(); i++)` seemed not to be executed.
`arraysObject1.array1` is empty.

Comment: You're right! I had not taken that possibility into account. Thank you.

Comment: I often make such bugs too :)